# Rails 4 and Active Admin: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, activemodel

The full error is the following:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Admin::ProductsController#create
```

My product model only has a `name` and `price`. **Why is `commit` a parameter?** When I click the 'Create Product' button within the admin dashboard, this is the params output:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"6/pCeklsaik4sYF5h8+WRPddkH7wJn9ZJHd6YLaaNuc=",
 "product"=>{"name"=>"Black Shirt Male",
 "price"=>"25"},
 "commit"=>"Create Product"}
```

From what I've gathered reading other Stack Overflow posts, you need to use strong parameters in Rails 4 instead of `attr_accessible`, which was done for me when I scaffolded the product model. In my `create` action in the Products controller, I have:

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
```

And product_params is defined as:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price)
end
```

I didn't do anything fancy when I created the model, and in my Gemfile I'm using the following as the documentation suggested for Rails 4:

```
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
```

**Why am I getting this error when I create a new product via the Active Admin dashboard? Any input on the matter is appreciated.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright figured it out. I'm not sure if this is the 'correct' way but the products are being created.

in app/admin/product.rb I did:

```
permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model, :name, :price
```

where

```
permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
```

was initially commented out. So I just added `:name` and `:price`

Comment: Actually ":list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model" is just the sample code, we do not need them :)

Answer (score 1):

Question already answered, but I'm adding this as a helpful resource to supplement this answer:

https://github.com/activeadmin/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters